# flutter : how to substring string from last of special character like @

Tags: flutter, substring

I have this string `ffff @fgggg @`, How can I do substring last @, Thats mean When I am using this code:

```
String text =  `ffff @fgggg @`;
selectedUser = text.substring();
```

I expect selectedUser be == "";

I want to check text from last @ ? If after last `@` be nothing, `substring()` method return "" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found answer :

```
 selectedUser = text.substring(text.lastIndexOf('@') + 1);
```

and I got "". It checked from last @.